# Confusion of I and he?

Tags: gods, advaita

If God is in everyone then why many swamijis referred to as him? He will save us, he will incarnate, he stays in kailsasa, he stays in vaikuntha, he wears this, he wears that etc.?

Comment: Because they realized the facts and others didn't...

Comment: Brahman has no sex. In Sanskrit, Brahman is neutral, neither male or female. It is only for lingual convention that It is often referred to as He.

Comment: Bramh also has Saguna and Sakar aspects, so it makes sense to personify Him (we use Her when talking about the Devi form). Also, ease of communication is an important factor. Being technically correct when talking about something is not an overriding consideration. We have to balance it with not making things too complicated or confusing.

Comment: Because its Kaliyuga and modern swamis are not powerful enough like ancient yogis, one of whom was sage Narayana and his incarnation Krishna told Arjuna to worship him in Geeta, Buddhists pray to Buddha etc., In reality highest omnipresent immortal God is formless, nameless, genderless entity expressed by silence through munis like Dakshinamurthy and not even interested in temporary creation called Maya.What people call gods with forms are ancient enlightened yogis and part of 33 koti Gods. In reality God is in everyone as their Atman/soul and main difference between living and dead person.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Brahman is all there is.  Having realized this, the jnani is not unable to use conventions of speech.

I may say, "I live in St. Petersburg, FL," but the "I" being referred to is the body-mind.  It is a convention of speech.  The body-mind resides in St. Petersburg, FL.  Conventions of speech also have people refer to the gender of the body in using pronouns...so there is the use of "he" and "she".

The jnani uses the words "I", "me", "he", "she", etc. differently than one who has not realized Brahman is all there is.  The jnani profoundly realized there is no "me"...but the word can still be used to refer to the body-mind.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. Please backup your answer with credible sources. Else the answer may get deletion.